# Writing code that so that when the user clicks on the button a new window will open containg detail from a listbox (not using tkinter)

Tags: python, guizero

I am having trouble where I am writing code where I take a csv file and populate it on a listbox, Then I am using another csv file to relate to the item on the first csv. When the user selects a car and pushes the button called "Get Info" under the listbox, a new window will open. That new window will contain detail on the selected item from my first csv file. When the user clicks on the second button called "Last 3 drivers" a new window will open that gives information relating to the first csv file from my second csv file.

Here is the full code

```
from guizero import App, ListBox, Text, TextBox, PushButton, Window

app = App("Cars", layout='grid')
app.height = 350
app.width =350
app.bg = 'gray'
text = Text(app, grid =[0,0], text="Buy a Car here!!!!!!\n(Cars are guaranteed to breakdown,no refunds)")
text2 = Text(app, grid= [0,70], text="Select the Car to learn more\n information about it")
text2.size = '10'
listbox = ListBox(app, grid = [0,50]) 
listbox.bg = 'white'
listbox.text_size = "10"

with open('Cars database.csv') as fh:
    for items in fh:
        items = items.split(",")
        listbox.append(items[1])
        
            
def Get_Info():
    with open('Cars database.csv') as fh:
        for items in fh:
            if listbox.value:
                window = Window(app)
                window.height = 250
                window.width = 250
                app.info = listbox.value
                for items in fh:
                    items = items.split(",")
                    output= "\nCar:" + items[1] + "\nModel:" + items[2] + "\nColor:" + items[3] + "\nBody-Style:" + items[4] + "\nAge:" + items[5] + "\nYear:" + items[6] + "\nEngine:" + items[7]
                    if items[1] == listbox.value:
                        txt = Text(window, text=output)
                        txt.size = '13'
            else:
                app.error('Error', text='You must select a car first')

def Last_Driv():
    with open('Cars Drivers.csv') as fh:
        for items2 in fh:
            if listbox.value:
                newwindow = Window(app)
                newwindow.height = 250
                newwindow.width = 250
                app.info = listbox.value
                for items2 in fh:
                    items2 = items2.split(",")
                    output2= "\nName:" + items2[1] + "\nCrashes:" + items2[2] + "\nName2:" + items2[3] + "\nCrashes2:" + items2[4] + "\nName3:" + items2[5] + "\nCrashes3:" + items2[6]
                    if items2[1] == listbox.value:
                        txt2 = Text(window, text=output2)
                        txt2.size = '13'
            else:
                app.error('Error', text='You must select a car first')
                

my_button = PushButton(app, text='Get Info', grid = [0,80], command = Get_Info)
my_button2 = PushButton(app, text='Last 3 Drivers', grid = [0,90], command = Last_Driv)
app.display()
```

On the second function, when you press the second button called "Last 3 drivers" It only displays a blank window, it doesnt display the items from my "Cars Drivers" csv file.

Heres what my window looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W50Xi.png)

And Heres what my window looks like when you press the second button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIbov.png)

There is also another problem If anyone can help me, I made an error window in case someone pressed the button without selecting an item, but once the pop up error window comes up and you it "ok" it will pop up another, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong window name

```
                        txt2 = Text(window, text=output2)
```

should be :

```
txt2 = Text(newwindow, text=output2)
```

For the error window repetition remove the for in this place, you already have the right one later

```
 with open('Cars database.csv') as fh:
        for items in fh: #REMOVE THIS
            if listbox.value:
```

Comment: Thank you, Do you think you can help me with the error pop up window that I have too. I still cant figure that out

Comment: @NasrullahHussain   yes i can try, but please do not forget to accept the answer i already gave you

Comment: @NasrullahHussain, done, PLEASE do not forget to accept the answer with  the checkmark

Comment: I didnt forget and my code is now working, thank you so much for this